# Callback to identify issue while loading UserTimeline using TweetTimelineListAdapter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am trying to use `UserTimeline` and `TweetTimelineListAdapter` to get `TimeLine` as could be found [here](http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html#listactivity) in fabric documentation. If I am using my open n/w and provided it has proper download speed, I am able to load Timeline properly. I am showing a `ProgressDialog` while Timeline is loaded initially.

**Issue:**

If I am in corporate n/w of office or if my 2G/3G n/w is too slow/intermittent, I am not sure how to figure out when it really timeouts and as such I am not sure when to dismiss `ProgressDialog`.

**Question:**

Is there any callback, that gets hooked on to `TweetTimelineListAdapter` or something similar, so that I can get if there is any error, timeout, etc while trying to load Timeline.

**My Approach at best:**

I am able to use a `DataSetObserver` and see if Timeline has loaded and dismiss. But nothing I could find out that gives me if there is any error, or timeout kind of issues while loading.

```
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(mTwitterDatasetObsv);

DataSetObserver mTwitterDatasetObsv = new DataSetObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        // dismiss progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        super.onInvalidated();
        // dismiss progress dialog
    }

};
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally figured it out myself, and answering my own question in case any one would be interested.

I was initially relying on following lines of code, where it has some abstract time to load Twitter timeline and in that mean time my Activity was blank. In order to cope up with latency, I showed `ProgressDialog`. But as mentioned in question above, I needed to know where to dismiss the dialog.

```
final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName(brandScreenName).build();

// create custom TimeLine adapter object
adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(this, userTimeline);
```

I found out that we can infact invoke following API available for `UserTimeline` to get `Callback` with `success` and `failure` methods.

```
// trigger userTimeline manually to get latest tweets
userTimeline.previous(null, new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>() {

    @Override
    public void success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {         
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {           
    }
});
```

But above alone, didn't solve my issue as for the first time `success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result)`was called with proper result, it was not refreshing `ListView` by notifying `adapter`. In order to deal with this, I created `class CustomTimeLineAdapter extends TweetTimelineListAdapter` and overridden methods such as `getItem`, `getCount` and `getView` to take `Tweet` from an `ArrayList` populating inside `success` callback mentioned above.

Comment: I have same problem , can you please send me your code or plaace it here

Comment: Please find the relevant code at https://pastelink.net/wd3 , let me know if you need any other help

Comment: How to use it , I cant Understand How it would help me in taking callback